# Edismax query not working after migrating to solr 7.7 from 6.6

Tags: solr, migration, edismax, query-parser, solr7

I have migrated to solr version 7.7 from 6.6
But after migrating to this version my edismax query is not working and returning 0 values.
My edismax query is something like this.

```
{!edismax qf='title' mm=1 k='("messi"^4.02 "ronaldinho"^2.01)' pf='title' ps=10 qs=4}
```

It's working on older version that is 6.6 and returning results as well.
Can anyone tell me what might be the issue ??

Comment: Handling of local params changed in Solr 7.2 - since exposing the `{!..}` syntax in other query parses to users could lead to exposing services you weren't planning to expose. See https://solr.apache.org/guide/7_7/solr-upgrade-notes.html#solr-7-2 - other than that, are you sure you have the same field types in both instances? Also I do not see an actual query in your example - did you mean `q` instead of `k`?

Comment: @MatsLindh Yes, same field in both instances. V instead of k messi is the query with boost of 4.02

Answer (score 1):

To work this out I have to set q.op=OR in params.
in Solr7.7 it takes q.op=AND by default.